# Why qemu is extremly slow? How to fast it up?

Tags: qemu

I have 4 kernels + 6G RAM notebook and run qemu+aarm64 there.

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-system-arm
sudo apt-get install qemu-efi-aarch64
sudo apt-get install qemu-utils
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash1.img bs=1M count=64
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash0.img bs=1M count=64
dd if=/usr/share/qemu-efi-aarch64/QEMU_EFI.fd of=flash0.img conv=notrunc
qemu-img create ubuntu-image.img 20G
```

then downloaded https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/arm64/iso-cd/debian-11.1.0-arm64-netinst.iso and run

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -nographic -machine virt,gic-version=max -m 3G -cpu max -smp 4 \
-netdev user,id=vnet,hostfwd=:127.0.0.1:0-:22 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vnet \
-drive file=ubuntu-image.img,if=none,id=drive0,cache=writeback -device virtio-blk,drive=drive0,bootindex=0 \
-drive file=debian-11.1.0-arm64-netinst.iso,if=none,id=drive1,cache=writeback -device virtio-blk,drive=drive1,bootindex=1 \
-drive file=flash0.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive file=flash1.img,format=raw,if=pflash
```

Emulator goes **extremely** slow, why?

Comment: You're emulating ARM 64 architecture on an Intel processor

Comment: @roaima It is AMD64 processor, is this the real matter?

Comment: AMD64 is Intel-like. You've downloaded the ARM architecture (mobile phones, Raspberry Pi, etc.)

Comment: @roamia yes, you are correct: host is x86_64 , guest is arm64. Is this the matter of slowness ?

Comment: Almost certainly. There will be little or no hardware support for the foreign architecture. (But I haven't tried this myself, so I can't say how slow it will actually run. That's why I'm only adding comments rather than a full answer.)

Comment: @roaima Thank you. I believe  that you are right

Comment: Translating an instruction set could be slower than even software virtualization.

Comment: Wait... How come you asked yesterday why it's slow, and today how to solve an installation issue ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675444

Comment: @jmr what? It is extremely slow working installer with issue

Comment: Ah. Reading the description, I failed to understand that it was the installer that was slow. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You have 4 kernels? Thank goodness for that!